# InstallReferrerClient.startConnection() throwing Caused by java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: android, crash-reports, install-referrer

```
 Caused by java.lang.SecurityException
    Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.google.android.finsky.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.externalreferrer.GetInstallReferrerService }
```

in  android project  i use new library `com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1`
when call this code

```
referrerClient.startConnection(new InstallReferrerStateListener()
```

occure the exception

in firebase crashReporter  reported this exception in 
samsung (Galaxy Note3 ,Galaxy Grand2, Galaxy A7) and HUAWEI (Y5II , G750-U10)

Android 5.1
 21%
Android 5.0
 10%
Android 5.0.2
 21%
Android 4.4.2
16%
Android 4.2.2

i check merged manifest and find this permission

```
android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE"
```

but not fount `tools:remove` tag

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a Google issue: There's an open ticket in their issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72926755